# How to better visualize a very skewed distribution

Tags: r

Im new to R and Im with some issues with graphs. I have a very skewed distribution and I think that because of that the graphs  I obtain are difficult to interpret.

For example I have a variable responsetime that the skewness is: 
 26.56731.

As you can see below the graphs Im having are hard for interpretation, do you know how can we handle this very skwed distributions?

A density plot like this:

```
plot(density(data$responsetime, xlim=c(0, 20000))
```

[image]

A plot like this:

```
plot(x=data$city, y=data$responsetime)
```

[image]

`data$responsetime` example:

```
c(9703L, 297L, 482L, 915L, 295L, 857L, 4379L, 301L, 785L, 492L, 295L, 893L, 544L, 292L, 924L, 490L, 301L, 788L, 544L, 294L, 826L, 485L, 293L, 9725L, 799L, 621L, 296L, 805L, 1218L, 294L, 810L, 458L, 295L, 487L, 9585L, 293L, 479L, 459L, 292L, 930L, 452L, 296L, 602L, 474L, 293L, 779L, 9747L, 698L, 292L, 799L, 8150L, 172L, 2229L, 3361L, 241L, 1423L, 1813L, 289L, 987L, 974L, 257L, 803L, 1980L, 558L, 942L, 1147L, 285L, 414L, 1676L)
```

Comment: does a log transform help?

Comment: Can you share `data$responsetime` or at least a representative sample / example of it please.

Comment: Just change the x limit (in my opinion). You can supplement this by quickly calculating what % of the data is in the viewable range. By the way, please use `dput()` to share data in the R tag. The current form is not easily reproducible. If your data is too big use simulated data.

Comment: If you want to plot on a log scale, add `log="x"` to your plot code, e.g., `plot(density(data$responsetime), xlim=c(0, 20000), log="x")`. Note also that your code has a misplaced parenthesis, which is why R is ignoring your `xlim`. It should be `plot(density(data$responsetime), xlim=c(0, 20000))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give a example how to do that? Im beginner and Im trying to do that but without success.

Comment: Are you talking to me or eipi10?

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing.

Comment: Rather than plotting the density, have you considered using `quantile`? or potentially using a box-and-whiskers plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

newdata = data %>% filter(response_time < 20000)

plot(density(newdata$responsetime, xlim=c(0, 20000))
```

if you instead want to look at the log transformed response then you can do

```
 plot(density(log(data$responsetime)))
```